# What does this tiny bookmark symbol mean in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio

I've looked all over and can't find an explanation for this symbol.
It's an extremely small bookmark with a number, and it usually appears just under code.
The challenge is that since it looks like a bookmark, virtually all searches bring up the wrong information.

If anyone can offer some insight, I would be very grateful.

[image: tinybookmark]

Comment: Is there any type of tooltip or message when you hover over it?

Comment: Also, what edition of Visual Studio?  And, if you look at View->Other Windows->Bookmark Window, does the content of the Bookmark Window seem to relate to the icon?